# Import specific part of a relative submodule in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

With a project structure like the following:

```
myproject/
 |--- __init__.py
 |--- application.py
 |--- modules/
       |--- __init__.py
       |--- parser.py
 |--- utils/
       |-- __init__.py
       |-- helpers.py
```

In `utils/helpers.py`:

```
def find_stuff():
    return stuff

def help_me():
    return some_help
```

In `modules/parser.py`, I want to import `find_stuff` (and only that).

I've tried the following:

```
from ..utils.helpers import find_stuff
```

But...

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'find_stuff' from 'myproject.utils.helpers' (/Users/myself/myproject/utils/helpers.py)
```

What should be done here?

Notes:

- everything was working fine with the whole project's policy of absolute import, until I started using Pytest, and then all hell broke loose
- no, I don't want to `from ..utils import helpers` and then use `helpers.find_stuff` in `parser.py` — I assume that Python's import system is well-thought enough so that we can precisely avoid that
- in the error message, we can see that Python manages to find the correct file, however for some reason it just won't import the function/class/object name, despite it being present in the file

Comment: I have duplicated the project from your question in PyCharm and it works for me.

Comment: @quamrana yes actually it works — the real case is that I have circular dependencies, and Python is quite terrible at managing them...

Comment: Well, you didn't specify that in your question. Don't have circular dependencies!

Comment: Seems that Python is making them more of a problem that they actually should be...

Answer (score 3):

Under `utils` you do not have an `__init__.py` file.  I think you will need one and even an empty one will do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake — the init file is actually there, see my edit

Answer (score 2):

Did you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/8002464) issue already? It depends on what you want to do. If you're writing something that is purely a module

```py
from myproject.utils.helpers import find_stuff
```

should work.